# Prestashop Website is not displaying?

Tags: web, content-management-system, themes, prestashop

I hope someone here will be able to solve my problem. I been trying to solve this for hours now. I have recently started building my website using PrestaShop. Everything was fine until i changed some pictures on website slideshow. Now i cant' see my website. Basically when i go on my website "www.smokeyjack.co.uk " website appears for a sec then disappears. i have tried deleting cookies, changing browsers, updating flash, but nothing seems to work. Please help me on this. i can't just figure it out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your logo is with the following size: "3508px x 4961px" and it covers all the page.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, i have changed logo back to it's original size & it has worked. Thank you. Can't believe something like this can have such an impact.

Comment: This question has now been answered, Thanks for help .